# Can you visually edit the html / view part of a asp.net project using Mono Develop?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, mono, monodevelop

I have downloaded and installed the windows binary installer for Monodevelop.

I started a new web/vb.net project but I can't really find how to switch to a "visual" view editor for the html page.

I also read here http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET_Visual_Designer where the MD devs say they have now integrated aspnetedit directly into monodevelop (as opposed, I guess, to being a standalone editor as it was before)

But then there are instruction on how to install it, and so i am puzzled.. If it is integrated in monodevelop, why now i am given instruction on how to install it ? 
Then I thought that for "integrated" they just meant to say that aspneteditor it's not anymore a different project per se, but lives into monodevelop source code, but for some reasons you still need to compile it separately...

Or am I getting this all wrong ?

Why can't monodevelop developers make a binary which includes aspnededit as well ?

Can anyone tell me then how to setup and use the AspNetEdit in MonoDevelop, if my approach is all wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the website, the editor is still not ready for production, so it's not shipped in the binaries. You will need to build and install it yourself.